# How To Read a HBASE EXTERNAL table made on HIVE using PRESTO

Tags: hive, hbase, presto

I made an external table on HIVE using

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table(rowkey string, event_platform string, event_current_authtype string, event_current_league_level int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, data:event_platform, data:event_current_authtype, data:event_current_league_level")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "test_table","hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "test_table");
```

I can successfully query this using HIVE but can't query this using Presto, I do have a hive catalog and query all other external tables(like tables from parquet files)

When I query using presto I end up getting this error

```
presto:default> select * from test_table limit 10;
Query 20230505_073116_00002_vk92d failed: InputFormat is not present in StorageFormat
```

I guess the Presto-hbase connector is deprecated, do we have a work around?